# App Inventor TinyWebDB List Problems

Tags: app-inventor

I got a problem using the `TinyWebDB` in App Inventor 2. Here's a Screenshot of the blockcode.

[image: Blockcode Screenshot]

The goal of this Screen is to store a list(array) of images and later query them with a button but my problem starts already earlier. First there is a variable initialized called fotoList and declared as an empty list.

When this Screen initializes (left block) I store the empty fotoList under the tag FotoListTag. Then if the image under the tag "SteckbriefFoto" is not in this list -> getValue with tag "FotoListTag". Then he jumps into the block on the right and adds the photo .. other stuff not important .. at the end I store the list again in the `TinyWebDB` (and also in the `TinyDB`) with the tag "FotoListTag". Then it goes back to the block on the left where at the end I want to set an image.picture to the photo I stored in variable fotoList.

When I compile the code there is an error opening the page that says

```
Select list item: List index too large 
Select list item: Attempt to get item number 1 of a list of length 0:()
```

I just don't get the problem with this code and i hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lists, `valueIfTagNotThere` should be `create empty list` instead of an empty string

On first run of your app, `TinyDB` is empty, which means, for tag = FotoListTag you get no value back, therefore this should be an empty list in the beginning.

Later you are trying to select the first item from the list (zahl is 1). As you know, the list is empty in the beginning, so probably you should add an `if` statement to check, if the list is not empty and only then select the first item... same for tag =  Schriftlist.

You also have a timing issue. in `Screen.Initialize` you are trying to get a value from `TinyWebDB`. This is an asynchronous call, you get the result back in `TinyWebDB.GotResult` event and this takes a little bit (let's say 500 milliseconds), but meanwhile the complete blocks of the `Screen.Initialize` event will be executed. Probably you are expecting, that meanwhile tag = FotolistTag is not empty anymore, but this is not the case.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for answering so late, it was the timing issue!